# Ionic Framework - force view to load page with latest data from controller

Tags: ionic-framework

Being new to Ionic, and AngularJS, please help on the following issue, where I try to load 2nd page upon `ng-click` event from the 1st page. I pass a parameter to the function associated with the `ng-click` function, where it populates data based on the parameter, and I use that data using `ng-repeate` on the 2nd page to render HTML.

CodePen link as follows:

http://codepen.io/lgframe/pen/dPGvWv/

It's a two-page TO-DO app, where 1st-page display `itemList` and when clicked, it should display buttons on the 2nd page.

1st Page:

Display a list of two items `($scope.dataArray)`, 
which has `ng-click="listitemClick($index)`

-> Mr-AA `($index=0)`

-> Mr-BB `($index=1)`

Function `listitemClick($index)` as follows: 
Based on the `index`, it reads data from `$scope.jsonData[index]`

```
  $scope.listitemClick = function(index) { 
       $scope.listItemIndex = index; 
       var listObj = $scope.jsonData[index]; 
       dayIndex = $scope.dayIndex; 
       $scope.btnNames = listObj[dayIndex]; 
   };
```

2nd page:

Display buttons for the listItems of the page1.
When the listItem of page1 clicked, it pass `$index(0,1 etc)` to the function `listItemClick()`.
This function, reads data from `$scope.jsonData[index]` and populate `$scope.btnNames`
Buttons are rendered using `ng-repate` on `$scope.btnNames`. With this value 2nd page should display related data, BUT it does not display any buttons. Looks like page is not getting latest value for `$scope.btnNames`.  PLAEASE HELP ME RE-LOAD THE PAGE

On the header of this 2nd Page, I have two navigation buttons associated with function a)`$scope.dayMinus()` and b) `$scope.dayPlus`, wherein these functions, I simply increment or decrease `$scope.dayIndex`. So, using `<< or >>` navigation buttons, I like to see the buttons for Mon, Tue, Wed 
Thus, update 2nd Page buttons, when the navigation buttons clicked

Im using router with .config, 
1st page1 has ui-srf for page2.html

On my local machine, I was NOT able to see the button on the 2nd page(page2.html), as page1.html may be in DOM ( I guess) prior to the `listItemClick()` function. I did search over the web, on force view to reload page, etc, but no luck so far.

On CodePen example, I put all the required code, where please tweak it and help me reload the 2nd page.

Comment: You Codepen does not seem to work, which makes it hard to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: I manage to resolve issue by removing code errors...thanks